# How to send cell number to the function in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to know how to get cell `number(indexPath.row)` in the following `tapPickView` function. `topView` is on the `UITableViewCell`, and `pickView` is on the `topView`. If `pickView` is tapped, `tapPickView` is activated.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
               "QuestionAndAnswerReuseIdentifier",
               forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionAndAnswerTableViewCell

    cell.topView.pickView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView")
    cell.topView.pickView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    return cell
}

func tapPickView() {
    answerQuestionView = AnswerQuestionView()
    answerQuestionView.questionID = Array[/*I wanna put cell number here*/]

    self.view.addSubview(answerQuestionView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to append `:` sign to your selector upon adding gesture recognizer in order for it to get the `pickView` as its parameter.

```
var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView:")
```

Besides that, cells are reusable objects, so you should prevent adding same gesture again and again to the same view instance by removing previously added ones.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionAndAnswerReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionAndAnswerTableViewCell
    cell.topView.pickView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.topView.pickView.tag = indexPath.row

    for recognizer in cell.topView.pickView.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
        cell.topView.pickView.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    cell.topView.pickView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapPickView:"))

    return cell
}
```

While populating the cell, you can set `tag` value of the `pickView` as `indexPath.row` so you can easily query that by `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)`.

```
cell.topView.pickView.tag = indexPath.row
```

*Assuming you already know the section of the cell you tap on. Let's say it is **0**.*

```
func tapPickView(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: recognizer.view.tag, inSection: 0)

    if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        print("You tapped on \(cell)")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this was not as simple as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, which I strongly recommend to first look into, passing the information to your method could look like this:

```
@IBAction func tapPickView:(sender: Anyobject) {
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell: cell)
        println(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.